# Core Data Error using swift: [SimpleRunner.Run setTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, appdelegate

I am currently trying to integrate Core Data into my project. At first I was not using Core Data, but then decided to, so I created a new project, then moved the code from the AppDelegate into the project I was working on. The name of my project is SimpleRunner, so far I just have one entity, Run. In my SimpleRunner.xcdatamodel I created Run Entity and assigned it to my Run class. Here is a picture of that [Run Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCRsd.png) and here is me assigning the Run class to it [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVh5k.png).However, when I try to save a run I get the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SimpleRunner.Run setTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.**

I know it is something small, someone please help!

**Run Object**

```
import CoreData
class Run:NSManagedObject{
@NSManaged var time:String
@NSManaged var distance:String
@NSManaged var runImage:Data?
}
```

**APP DELEGATE**

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "derivative.DataDemo" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = FileManager.default().urlsForDirectory(.documentDirectory, inDomains: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.main().urlForResource("SimpleRunner", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SimpleRunner.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR in Save Run Method where run.time = time**

```
  func saveRun(time:String,distance:String,image:UIImage){

    run = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Run", into: managedObjectContext) as! Run

    run.time = time <--------- WHERE THE ERROR IS
    run.distance = distance
    run.runImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Run entity does not have an attribute named `time`.

Comment: I changed that, deleted the app from my phone, then ran it again. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Try clean build and cleaning up your simulator.

Comment: I am getting the same issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same issue with Xcode 8 beta 2. (You may be using beta 1? Try updating your Xcode.) Exactly the same entity settings, almost the same code (fixed some parts for beta 2). Some other parts of your app (other codes, build settings and build process, or Xcode version) may be affecting, but I cannot see what can affect.

Comment: So something weird is happening in my xcmodeldata file. I mistakenly named one of my attributes "name". I then changed it to time. Now, for some reason the attribute changes itself back to name. When I changed the code back to name, it worked.

Comment: I see. Xcode sometime does weird things. Try the latest Xcode and create a new project with the right settings. (You better not copy xcdatamodeld.) Hope you can return to the usual development course soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring the class name in the model?  I see that you are force casting the results of `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject...` into `Run` (which is a bad thing to do btw) and it might actually be a `NSManagedObject` if you did not set the class correctly.

> Why is it a bad thing and how would you implement it?

You are basically lying to the compiler and not giving your code an "out" if your forced cast proves to be wrong.

You are better off with something like:

```
guard let run = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Run", into: managedObjectContext) as? Run else { 
  //Do something here
}
```

or even:

```
if let run = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Run", into: managedObjectContext) as? Run {
  //Put your logic here
}
```

Since this is a situation of "Developer Error" I would use the guard and a fatalError inside of the closure.

If you are developing for iOS10 you can skip all of that btw and just use:

```
let run = Run(context: managedObjectContext)
```

Comment: Why is it a bad thing and how would you implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my xcode version. I was using Xcode 8 version 1 beta, once I switched to version 2 it worked. Note to self: Use stable version when learning